# How to replace text which is not in the DOM while page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not an expert in javascript or jQuery.  I want to replace a text that is not in the DOM while the page loads. After clicking a button the text appears.
This is the code I am using....

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.shippingquote', function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Free Shipping/g,'Free Shipping (4-8 days)'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by, "replace a text that is ***not*** in the document while the page loads."

Comment: You could to that with JQuery onCompleted() callback for document.

Comment: you can do that immediately after the page is  loaded

Comment: The text "Free Shipping" is not in the Dom while the page loads ..... I want to replace the "Free shipping" with "Free Shipping (4-8 days)"

Comment: And you want to do that anytime anything on the page changes?

Comment: What is it that loads the text into the DOM?

Comment: I have to click a button "Estimate Shipping Taxes" After click the button the text "Free Shipping" loads into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ $('body').html("Free Shipping, Free shipping")});
```

This this block of code by replacing your complete code you mentioned at the top.
It will set the given text in complete body.
If, you wanna set the text of particular container (div, paragraphs, span etc)
then give the id in the selector.

```
$(function(){$('#id').html("text goes here")});
```

Good luck..

Comment: actually he did not ask for how to set content of an element.

Comment: He is asking to replace the text while the page load and my code will do the same.

Comment: yes you are right  codehx. Chanchal didn't understood my question. Anyways Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "$(function () {...});" to run code once the page has loaded and don't need to bind it to the load event.
The following code will replace all occurrences of Free Shipping on page load.

```js
$(function(){
        $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/Free Shipping/g,'Free Shipping (4-8 days)'));
});
```

MutationObservers have been brought in to do what you want to, but support from browsers is still low (ie11). I've used DOMSubtreeModified, which whilst depricated works on ie9+. I've also had to use a global variable to stop the event from being repeatedly called (would love a better suggestion for this).

```js
var modifiedByFunction = false;

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("input").on("click", function(e) {
    jQuery(".shippingquote").html("The words Free Shipping are in this");
  });

  jQuery(".shippingquote").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    if (modifiedByFunction) {
      modifiedByFunction = false;
    } else {
      modifiedByFunction = true;
      jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace(/Free Shipping/g, 'Free Shipping (4-8 days)'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click me">
<div class="shippingquote"></div>
```

Comment: The Text "Free Shipping" is not in the DOM while the page load. After clicking a Button the Text appears so your code is not working.

Comment: "I am using this code which works by clicking the Free shipping but the text should replace while the page loads not by clicking on it."
How can it replace it while the page loads if it's not there when it loads. Could you edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I need to replace a text "Free Shipping" to "Free Shipping (4-8 days)". The text is not in the DOM. After clicking a certain button the text loads....The above mentioned code which I am using changes the text "Free Shipping" to "Free Shipping (4-8 days)" if I click on the text "Free Shipping".... But I dont want it to happen on click .

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

The load event is deprecated in version 1.8 of jQuery.

> [click here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

The second:
i agree with [chanchal yadav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3989757/chanchal-yadav) about that.